# How to sort x-axis and get bar labels using plt

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using a subplot to plot 3 dataframes as below:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], size = 20),
                   'score' : np.random.normal(size = 20)})
df1['score'] = np.abs(df1['score'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], size = 20),
                   'score' : np.random.normal(size = 20)})
df2['score'] = np.abs(df2['score'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], size = 20),
                   'score' : np.random.normal(size = 20)})
df3['score'] = np.abs(df3['score'])
```

for which I am getting:

[image]

Could someone please let me know how to order x-axis from `a` to `e` and get the value labels on the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes

np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], size=20), 'score': np.random.normal(size=20)})
df1['score'] = np.abs(df1['score'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], size=20), 'score': np.random.normal(size=20)})
df2['score'] = np.abs(df2['score'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], size=20), 'score': np.random.normal(size=20)})
df3['score'] = np.abs(df3['score'])

# Create a figure and a set of subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))

def plot_df(ax: Axes, df: pd.DataFrame, title: str) -> None:
    """
    Plot a DataFrame as a bar chart on a given matplotlib Axes without annotations.

    Parameters:
    - ax (Axes): The matplotlib Axes object where the chart will be plotted.
    - df (pd.DataFrame): The DataFrame containing the data to plot. 
                         It must have columns 'id' and 'score'.
    - title (str): The title for the subplot.

    Returns:
    None
    """
    # Sort by 'id' column for ordered plotting
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='id')
    ax.bar(df_sorted['id'], df_sorted['score'])

    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel('ID')
    ax.set_ylabel('Score')
    # Ensure the x-axis has fixed categories
    ax.set_xticks(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

# Plot each DataFrame
plot_df(axs[0], df1, 'DataFrame 1')
plot_df(axs[1], df2, 'DataFrame 2')
plot_df(axs[2], df3, 'DataFrame 3')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might consider using [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) here.

Comment: I am seeing many values, seemingly random, appear inside all the bars.

Comment: @KarthikS should be good now, try again

Comment: I need the bar label value on the top the bars. The updated code has removed those!

Comment: @KarthikS https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982 or [`Axes.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html).

Comment: @KarthikS if you found your answer could you close this question please